# VB.NET - Localizar texto em arquivo XML

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

Preciso de uma ajuda para fazer a validação de um arquivo XML que estou usando como banco de dados.

Eu faço a inserção dos dados corretamente, porém preciso fazer uma validação para não inserir arquivos repetidos, portanto preciso verificar se o texto já existe dentro do XML.

Meu arquivo XML está da seguinte forma:

```
<Musicas>
  <Musica>
    <Nome>Musica1</Nome>
    <Path>D:\teste\Musicas\Musica1.txt</Path>
  </Musica>
  <Musica>
    <Nome>Musica2</Nome>
    <Path>D:\teste\Musicas\Musica2.txt</Path>
  </Musica>
</Musicas>
```

Preciso validar se o conteúdo das tags Nome já existem.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente é necessário saber o seguinte para responder sua pergunta:

- Se já fez o interpretador do arquivo XML e,
- Como está lidando com cada elemento.

Supondo que está utilizando uma classe dinâmica, que há as propriedades `Nome` e `Path`, enumere os elementos do XML com uma lista fantasma, adicionando cada nome na lista.

> Abaixo é um pseudo-código, cujo feito para você entender o algoritmo.

```
Variável ListaFantasma é uma nova Lista (de string)
Sendo XmlElement cada elemento XML no arquivo, faça:
    Se ListaFantasma contém XmlElement -> Nome:
         // Contém o nome, o que fazer agora?
    Caso contrário:
         // Não contém o nome
    Fim do Se
Fim do Sendo
```

O pseudo-código acima em Visual Basic .NET seria mais ou menos assim:

```
Public Class MusicaItem
     Public Property Nome As String
     Public Property Path As String
End Class
...
Dim Musicas As New List(Of MusicaItem)

Dim ListaFantasma As New List(Of String)
For Each Musica As MusicaItem In Musicas
    If ListaFantasma.Contains(Musica.Nome) Then
         ' Contém o nome
    Else
         ' Não contém o nome
         ...
         ' Sempre adicione o nome para saber que ele já passou por aqui
         ListaFantasma.Add(Musica.Nome)
    End If
Next
```

No código acima, já criei a classe dinâmica para cada elemento no seu XML. O item `Musica.Nome` é adicionado a lista fantasma, assim, sempre é verificado se o item já existe na lista.

---

Caso não elaborou um código para interpretar o XML, considere abrir uma nova pergunta, ou aprenda a [ler arquivos XML com Visual Basic](http://www.macoratti.net/10/08/vbn_xml1.htm).

Answer (score 0):

O framework já resolveu isso faz tempo. Serialize sua classe!

Não faça de forma procedural, use a orientação à objetos em seu favor. Teoricamente você cria uma classe que reflete seu XML, a preenche e depois a serializa e tem como retorno um XML em formato de string. dai você pode salvá-lo localmente, por exemplo.

[Exemplo de como fazer Classe -> XML](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm)